# Is there a way to determine where messages came from in a Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

There is large amounts of data being pushed into one of our Kafka topics, is there a way to determine which producer this data is coming from?

Comment: I don't know of any functionality like that, but depending on what the message content is you might be able to send that information yourself.

Comment: Maybe you can make use of headers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without SASL or [`Authorizer`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/security/auth/Authorizer.scala) level auditing, no there is not an easy way other than tracking down connected, suspicious client-id via JMX.

I would suggest you enforce a standard message format and spread the word to producer teams. For example, look at the Cloudevents spec, which includes a source field

https://github.com/cloudevents/spec/blob/master/kafka-protocol-binding.md

Comment: You could apply quotas or throttles to the topic, and see who contacts you / cluster administrators

Comment: We have SASL enabled, is there an easy way to check which SASL user produced the messages?

Comment: I'm only familiar with Ranger or OpenPolicyAgent for tracking down client ids... Another option would be to try using `tcpdump` to see where traffic comes from

Comment: you could also set a custom Authorizer that can log operations. even without any security you could tell the source IP address

Comment: @radai Right, that's what the Ranger plugin mentioned above would do

Answer (score 4):

You can enable [quotas for the clients/users](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotasconfig), and then monitor which clients get throttled via two [quota-related JMX MBeans](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#monitoring) - bandwidth and request rate:

> Metric: **Bandwidth quota metrics** per (user, client-id), user or client-id
>  
>   MBean:
>   `kafka.server:type={Produce|Fetch},user=([-.\w]+),client-id=([-.\w]+)`
>   What it shows:: Two attributes. throttle-time indicates the amount of
>   time in ms the client was throttled. Ideally = 0. byte-rate indicates
>   the data produce/consume rate of the client in bytes/sec. For (user,
>   client-id) quotas, both user and client-id are specified. If
>   per-client-id quota is applied to the client, user is not specified.
>   If per-user quota is applied, client-id is not specified.
>
> Metric: **Request quota metrics** per (user, client-id), user or client-id
>   MBean: `kafka.server:type=Request,user=([-.\w]+),client-id=([-.\w]+)`
>  
>   What it shows: Two attributes. throttle-time indicates the amount of
>   time in ms the client was throttled. Ideally = 0. request-time
>   indicates the percentage of time spent in broker network and I/O
>   threads to process requests from client group. For (user, client-id)
>   quotas, both user and client-id are specified. If per-client-id quota
>   is applied to the client, user is not specified. If per-user quota is
>   applied, client-id is not specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can use headers, and hardcode producer id in the header before producing! That's something I'm doing in Node.js using rdkafka, java also should have it!

Answer (score 0):

1. use tcpdump on kafka broker to get packets send to 9092
2. use wireshark to filter specific kafka topic (kafka.topic.name == "xxx")
3. check the message body to get correct packet then find out source